# Slope of tangent line in a function

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the slope of the tangent line for the point $(\frac{1}{4},
> > g(\frac{1}{4}))$ where $g(x) = \frac{x^2e^{4x}}{4}$.

I "did" this in two ways: by definition and by deriving. I can derive $g$ and check the derivative on $x=\frac{1}{4}$. But I'm stuck doing it by the definition.

This is my attempt so far:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}}  \frac{g(x) - g(\frac{1}{4})}{x-\frac{1}{4}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}} \frac{ \frac{x^2e^{4x}}{4} - \frac{e}{4 \times 16}}{x-\frac{1}{4}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}} \frac{ x^2e^{4x} - \frac{e}{16}}{4x-1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}} \frac{ 16x^2e^{4x} - e}{16(4x-1)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}} \frac{ (16x^2e^{4x-1} - 1)e}{16(4x-1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You can either use the L^Hopital's rule or the following approximation:
$$
e^u\approx 1+u\quad,\quad |u|<<1
$$
where $u=4x-1$.